# Polynomial Degree Help

Tags: polynomials

A nonzero polynomial with rational coefficients has all of the numbers$$1+\sqrt{2}, \; 2+\sqrt{3}, \;3+\sqrt{4},\; \dots, \;1000+\sqrt{1001}$$ as roots. What is the smallest possible degree of such a polynomial?

Since there are $1000$ terms, adding the radical conjugates, there will be $2000$ terms. Thus, I got the smallest possible degree would be $2000$. What am I missing here?

Comment: $3+\sqrt4=5$ and $3-\sqrt4=1$ are not conjugates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite.

Think about $3+\sqrt{4}$: that's just $5$. A similar case holds for $8+\sqrt{9}$, etc. You would count each of those cases only **once**. How many such cases are there? Can you proceed?

> You must count the cases from $\sqrt{2^2}$ to $\sqrt{31^2}$, for a total of $30$ cases. That means the smallest possible degree is $1970$.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you. I forgot that some of the numbers are whole numbers and don't have radical conjugates.